# How do I run a command on creation of a new file?

Tags: save, autocmd

I'm aiming to make scripts I write in a certain directory (or of a certain extension) automatically executable on creation. I can do this whenever a file is written to, using [the following `autocmd`](https://askubuntu.com/a/546239/158442):

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py silent execute "! chmod +x %"
```

What I don't like is that this runs every time the file is written. If I had decided to reset the permissions of a particular script, I wouldn't want it to be set again, for example. And if the command is expensive, or is not idempotent, it would be undesirable to run it again and again. While this particular example uses `chmod`, please consider a more general case.

There is an event for when a buffer is created for a new file ([`BufNewFile`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events)), but is there some way to do this when such a buffer is written the first time?

Comment: This is hackish, but perhaps you could use `BufNewFile` to trigger the creation of an autocommand with a `BufWritePost`. After the event for `BufWritePost` finishes, delete the `BufWritePost` autocommand.

Comment: @void-pointer I considered doing that, then I stopped to wonder if there's a more elegant way - perhaps I had misunderstood the meaning of some event or something like that.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Vimscript, but after going through `help au`, it doesn't seem like there's a mechanism in place to fire an autocommand on the first write only.

Comment: I wonder if this problem should be handled by the OS, not by Vim. [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/44534/232568) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Set a cookie (some `b:` variable with an unique name) from a `BufNewFile`, check for the same cookie from a `BufWritePost`, then delete it after you write the file.

Comment: @lcd047 that's what Dhruva's method does (`b:is_new` in his case).

Comment: Nope, that has two drawbacks: (1) `BufWritePre` stats the file before every write; `BufNewFile` is run only once; and (2) it `chmod`s the file multiple times if you write the file multiple times in the same session (that is, it doesn't `unlet` the cookie).

Comment: @lcd047 Hmm, true. Want to post an answer or edit that post?

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer thread in these waters nowadays, just making guest appearances every now and then. :)

Comment: @lcd047 you worried about the license changes too?

Comment: Right now I have a pretty interesting research project that takes most of my time.  But yes, I also happen to disagree with the licence change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would set the file to be executable after writing to the file if it's not already executable

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py
    \  if getfperm(expand('%')) !~# 'x'
    \|   silent execute "! chmod +x %"
    \| endif
```

I think this should be the better approach.

To make only a new file executable:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py
    \  if !filereadable(expand('%'))
    \|   let b:is_new = 1
    \| endif
autocmd BufWritePost *.py
    \  if get(b:, 'is_new', 0)
    \|   silent execute '!chmod +x %'
    \|   let b:is_new = 0
    \| endif
```

Comment: Perfect. I took a stab at deriving the command myself but I wasn't smart enough to with vim primitives. Hopefully that will change in future.

Answer (score 2):

I use a different solution for this, with a script I called `xvim`:

```
#!/bin/sh

vim -p "$@"
for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && chmod a+x "$f"
done
```

I put this in my `~/bin` (make sure this is in your `PATH`), and also linked  `xvi` to it.

The advantage of this, is that I explicitly control which files are executable, rather than just assuming that all `.*.py` files should be executable (files in modules usually aren't). You also don't need to set it up for all filetypes (`*.rb`, `*.sh`, etc.).

If you don't want `xvim` to overwrite existing permissions, you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in "$@"; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && continue
    touch "$f"
    chmod a+x "$f"
done
vim -p "$@"
```

Note that this will create the files immediately when you run `xvim file` (this is different from `vim`).

Comment: I suppose for my case it would be: `[ -f "$f" ] || {touch "$f" && chmod +x "$f"}` *before* `vim`. But yes, combined with `vim -p` this would be very useful for me.

Comment: @muru Normally, when you do `vim newfile`, it doesn't make the file *until* you write it for the first time. So this works better the same as the default vim behaviour... And because you run this command explicitly (and not on every `:w`), running the `chmod` on existing files *as well* can be considered a feature, and not a bug :-)

Comment: This does suffer from the same flaw is Dhruva's original answer - I don't want the action run on an existing file or repeatedly over the same file. In my case, solidly a bug.

Comment: @muru But you *only* run this when you create the file (once). Then when you edit it the next time, you just use `vim` and none of this gets run (that's how I use it, anyway).

Comment: Remembering that sort of stuff (use x for this and y for that) is what I have vim and zsh for. :P

Comment: @muru Well, the point is your script never know which files you want executable anyway. Not all .py files are supposed to be executable... So a "human decision" is needed at some point.